# Accompanist Pager animateScrollToPage doesn't scroll to next page correctly

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

Using `accompanist-pager` version `0.25.1`, `animateScrollToPage()` doesn't seem to scroll all the way to make the next page fully visible, the previous page is still shown. The non animated version `scrollToPage()` seems to work fine however. Am I missing some additional params ?

```
@ExperimentalPagerApi
@Composable
fun MyPager() {
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
    HorizontalPager(
        count = 10,
        state = pagerState
    ) { pagerIndex ->
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(150.dp)
                .background(if (pagerIndex.mod(2) == 0) Color.Cyan else Color.Red)
        )
    }
    with(pagerState) {
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = currentPage) {
            launch {
                delay(10000)
                animateScrollToPage(
                    page = (currentPage + 1).mod(pageCount)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There is some issue with latest version of accompanist-pager 0.25.1. Works fine with 0.24.1-alpha and below versions.

Comment: I 've tried 0.23.1 and 0.24.1-alpha versions and it seems that this thing does not work

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that the pagerState updates before the animation ends. To fix this provide another key

```
var key by remember { mutableStateOf(flase) }

LaunchedEffect(key1 = key) {
    launch {
        delay(2000)
        with(pagerState) {
            val target = if (currentPage < pageCount - 1) currentPage + 1 else 0
            animateScrollToPage(page = target) //Broken
            key = !key
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that while `animateScrollToPage()` is running, the `pagerState.currentPage` changes and causes the `LaunchedEffect` to get recomposed. According to the official document of [LaunchedEffect](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#LaunchedEffect(kotlin.Array,kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)):

> The coroutine will be cancelled and re-launched when LaunchedEffect is recomposed with any different keys

Therefore, recomposition of the `LaunchedEffect` will cancell the running coroutine(which is animating the pager).

**One solution**(as mentioned in other answers) is to provide a custom key to the `LaunchedEffect` and change it manually after calling the `animateScrollToPage()`.

**Another solution** is to create a coroutine scope outside of the `LaunchedEffect` using `rememberCoroutineScope()` and launch the animation inside it. So the code will be like this:

```
    with(pagerState) {
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = currentPage) {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                delay(10000)
                animateScrollToPage(
                    page = (currentPage + 1).mod(pageCount)
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

With this approach, the coroutine will not get cancelled on recomposition of `LaunchedEffect`

Comment: Your answer saved my day!! thanks man!!

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same problem,In the end I chose to roll back the version of accompanist-pager to 0.24.1-alpha.

Answer (score 2):

Referencing the above answer,
it work fine in 0.29.0-alpha with code below

```
    with(pagerState) {
        if (pageCount > 0) {
            var key by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
            LaunchedEffect(key1 = key) {
                launch {
                    delay(5000)
                    val nextPage = (currentPage + 1).mod(pageCount)
                    animateScrollToPage(
                        page = nextPage
                    )
                    key = nextPage
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I took the previous answers and created a composable to handle this:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun CarouselAutoPlayHandler(
    pagerState: PagerState,
    carouselSize: Int
) {
    var pageKey by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    val effectFlow = rememberFlowWithLifecycle(pagerState.interactionSource.interactions)

    LaunchedEffect(effectFlow) {
        effectFlow.collectLatest {
            if (it is DragInteraction.Stop) pageKey++
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(pageKey) {
        delay(5000)
        val newPage = (pagerState.currentPage + 1) % carouselSize
        pagerState.animateScrollToPage(newPage)
        pageKey++
    }
}
```

Explanation:

1. Pass the pager state and the amount of items
2. Create a new key and set the initial value as 0 (the value here doesn't matter)
3. Remember the flow returned from the interactions property in the pager state (You can find the implementation in [this article](https://euryperez.dev/consuming-flows-safely-in-non-composable-scopes-in-jetpack-compose-d0154565bd68) I wrote)
4. Collect the flow and whenever there's a drag stop, add 1 to the page key so the LaunchedEffect below is restarted
5. In another LaunchedEffect set the pageKey as the key, add whatever your delay is and after that add the logic to scroll to the next page and change the pageKey to restart the LaunchedEffect once again

The code in the first LaunchedEffect will restart the time whenever the user manually drags the carousel.

You can pass the delay value as a variable, just kept it there hardcoded for the example.